# Подкасты для изучения С#

Tags: c#

Может, встречал кто подкасты на тему С#, для изучения языка. Я понимаю, что по подкастам язык не выучить, но как доп. материал может быть полезным.

Comment: А что такое **"подкаст"** ?

Comment: Не люблю я таких вопросом, мы же не гугл =) но чем тебе хабр уже не нравится? или самому лень поискать.. типа информация дефицитная.. 

Comment: Да, информация дефицитная, я склоняюсь к тому, что нет таких подкастов. Вопрос задал, после поиска по гуглу.

Comment: обычно в подкастах рассказывают про интересные вещи или какие-то иследования, а не основы, и их хватает на мсдне, рсдне и хабре

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3

Comment: Автор не гуглил, если утверждает, что данная информация дефицитная - их ВАЛОМ !!!! Не считая даже те ресурсы, к-е указаны выше.

Comment: Будьте добры, укажите пару ресурсов из списка "Валом". Буду очень вам признателен.

Comment: " мсдне, рсдне и хабре" или тебе линки надо прямые? или ты про эти ресурсы некогда не слышал?

Comment: Мне нужны конкретно подкасты. Данные ресурсы я знаю.

Comment: Например: http://www.techdays.ru/

Comment: Понятно...
Я имел в виду audio подкасты. Простите за не уточнение.

Comment: Еще много видео инфы на сайте мелкософта, по тому же мвц к примеру. А что касается просто аудио кастов без видео... никогда такого не видел, зачем оно вам? Типа чтобы не читать книгу, а в плеере ее прослушать? ))

Comment: Я и книгу читаю, и на курсы хожу и пытаюсь практиковаться в свободное время, но част бывает свободное время когда рядом нет вычислительных машин и дабы оно не пропадало в пустую, я хотел бы слушать теорию в наушниках. Как то так.

Comment: Вас понял, но подобную инфу нигде не встречал, возможно потому что меня она никогда не интересовала.
ПС обзаведитесь бумажным Рихтером и носите везде с собой =)

Comment: прикинул такой расклад, ложусь спать, а пока засыпаю, ставлю в уши "сказка о приведении типов в шапре" =) возможно даже, что производители освежителей для воздуха, если бы печатали мануалы по шарпу на своих баллончиках, стали зарабатывать больше

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подкастов именно на тему C# не встречал. По .Net в свое время слушал [Подкасты Петербургской группы Alt.Net](http://spbaltnet.rpod.ru/.)

Comment: Да, есть такие подкасты, но к сожалению они рассчитаны на уже знающих людей и разработчиков.

Comment: В какой то мере так, но я себя не считаю знающим или разработчиком, но послушать было интересно.

Answer (score 0):

Почитай тут, может поможет: [Видеоматериалы, блоги и подкасты для .NET разработчика](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142442/)

Answer (score 0):

RadioDotNet и DotNet & More
Оба на русском

channel9, например этот https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/The-development-of-modern-applications-in-C-

Начитка ответов на экзамен - https://anchor.fm/u0410u043bu0435u043au0441u0430u043du0434u044093